# Security with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been building a site with Laravel 5.2 and now i'm trying to make my forms more secure, i have used laravel's built in validation to only allow so many characters and required certain field.
Should i be using trim or other forms of validation to make my forms more secure i been looking at the below or does laravel have a lot more security built into it to help.

```
$data = trim($id); //security
  $data1 = stripslashes($id); //security
  $data1 = htmlspecialchars($id);
```

Comment: Tried the Validator class?

Comment: if you are using blade then blade will already do those for you. If you are talking about database security then their database class already handles that for you. Laravel is made to be simple but efficient and secure. If you are using Laravel correctly you will not need to add anything extra.

Comment: you better read https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation

Answer (score 3):

1. `trim()` doesn't do anything for security
2. `stripslashes()` will be undone when saved using Eloquent or the Query Builder.
3. `htmlspecialchars()` is for displaying data and not storing.

All of this is done by Laravel already. Whenever you are showing `user input` simply `{{ $display_it }}` to have `blade` automatically take care of XSS attacks.

As far as securing form data is concerned - Laravel's database queries are all parameterized, which means that there's no possibility of SQL injection.

The rest of your question is too broad to be answered, as you're thinking of security like a lock on a door, but security is more like wearing a glove to pick up a hot pan. It should be applied logic, not generalized.

Comment: I just read somewhere that triple might escape the same as double so removed comment to read more into it :p

Comment: just fyi - `Laravel 5.0 escapes all output from both the {{ }} and {{{ }}} Blade directives. A new {!! !!} directive has been introduced to display raw, unescaped output.`  so I guess you were technically correct before haha

Comment: @Matt Yea, The triple/double will do the same, but it's misleading as `{{{}}}` support was only provided really for people doing migrations. I'm sure it will be removed in `5.6 LTS`. And we should be using `{!! !!}` when we don't care about XSS, absolutely.